Hair twitches in shape change
I created a figure with a beard in Blender, but when I reduce the figure, the beard, created in particles, distorts. I tried to make the beard 'convert to mesh' but it turned black (in the picture) and you can't add texture to it. How can the beard be fixed in another way?

Convert the particles to the new hair curves. The curves can be scaled and converted back to particles. Or you can keep them and texture them like particles.

thank you ,But where do I have the option to convert new hair to curves? In modifiers properties there is only the option of convert to mesh

it's in the drop-down menu of the particle system -> https://i.sstatic.net/Q3tsMtnZ.jpg. After the conversion you need to attach the hair curves to the surface object (scalp/head). Here is a checklist: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/324382/107598. When the curves are a child of the surface object (Ctrl+P) they will scale with the model.
